# Humongous allocation: how can I ask jvm to print a log if humongous allocation happens

Tags: java, jvm, g1gc

I am using G1GC.

Is there a jvm argument I can pass to jvm so I get a gc log every time Humongous allocation happens?

Comment: How big is **Humongous**

Comment: I don't get your question. How many lines of code do you have that would instantiate *humongous* arrays or objects that would require *humongous* amounts of memory? In other words: what is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I am talking about G1GC humongous allocation.

Comment: Have a look - https://plumbr.eu/handbook/gc-tuning-in-practice/other-examples/humongous-allocations

Comment: @conscells The log in that blog only get printed if the total old gen size reaches the threshold. It actually takes a couple hundred humongous allocation for the total old gen size to breach the threshold. What I want is a log that get printed every time a humongous allocation happens

Comment: In that case you might need a tool like jvisualvm or Yourkit. I'm not sure if they have this feature

Comment: jmc can record allocations outside TLAB, which generally tend to be large allocatons, yourkit can filter allocation profiling by object size.

Answer (score 4):

```
-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+G1PrintHeapRegions
```

On every humongous allocation this will emit `G1HR ALLOC(StartsH)` or `G1HR ALLOC(SingleH)` line. Caution: this option will cause much more debug information printed to GC log or console.